# When the branch name contains underscores Jenkins changes them to hyphens for the archive directory

Tags: linux, jenkins-pipeline

I have a branch called CDU-009_hi_john and am running a Jenkins multibranch pipeline build. I have changed the default jenkins archive function to an sftp for performance reasons, but the cd to the directory that will contain the outputs is failing as the directory does not exist. After investigation I see that jenkins has created the following directory:

/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/CDM-Project/jobs/CDM-MultiBranch-Pipeline/branches/CDU-009-hi-john.2ujcja/builds/10/archive

Jenkins changes the underscores to hyphens and adds a weird 6 character string to the end. Looking at all my other pipelines this seems to be consistent behaviour, but is only an issue on the pipelines that I want to use sftp (larger output to return).

I wondered if there was a jenkins environment variable that might tell me where Jenkins is putting stuff but have listed all the obvious one:

```
10:16:18  echo jenkinsHome /var/lib/jenkins
10:16:18  echo jobName /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/CDM-Project/CDM-MultiBranch-Pipeline/CDU-009_hi_john/
10:16:18  echo jobBaseName CDU-009_hi_john
10:16:18  echo jobUrl http://pthdbb01.21csw.com.au:8080/job/CDM-Project/job/CDM-MultiBranch-Pipeline/job/CDU-009_hi_john/
10:16:18  echo branchName CDU-009_hi_john
```

Of course, if I use hyphens in the branch name I have no problem. So I can make that a naming condition, but don't want to be so restrictive.

I could not find any hits on Google, and stackoverflow normally has the answer as I am seldom the first person to get a problem!

My Jenkins is running on Ubuntu on Linux. Jenkins version is 2.426.2